# pagination in custom post type issue

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i faced very weird issue. I make a post type "insight" and now i want a pagination (No Plugin). when i click on next post it shows me 404 error

here is code

```
<?php
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ){
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        }
        else {
            $paged = 1;
        }


    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'insight','posts_per_page'=>'1','order'=>'DESC', 'paged' => $paged)); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="navigation">
     <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; New Entries') ?></div>
     <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
</div>
```

I don't no why this happen because i think my code right.

Answer (score 0):

Foy my blog I use this:

Functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
function my_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
}
endif;
```

and then after the endwhile, in the page that I want to use the pagination like categories, index etc... I use:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php my_pagination(); ?>
```

I hope this helps if you try it :)

Edit - to see it in action visit: http://ios-blog.co.uk

Comment: can you post the full code for the page that you are trying to get the pagination on?